# Is there a "accummulate_if"?

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a function similar to `accummulate()` but provides a unary pre-condition to filter the linear container when performing the operation? I search for `accummulate_if` but there isn't any. Thanks!

update:
Thanks for all the kind answers. I end up doing it this way:

`std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](int x){if (Pred) sum += x;});`

Comment: You should make your `for_each`-based approach an answer rather than an edit to the question, because, well, that's what it is. It's also the one you "accepted" after all.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Pass your own binary op to [std::accumulate()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

bool meets_criteria(int value) {
    return value >= 5;
}

int my_conditional_binary_op(int a, int b) {
    return meets_criteria(b) ? a + b : a;
}

class my_function_object {
private:
    int threshold;
public:
    my_function_object(int threshold) :
            threshold(threshold) {
    }

    bool meets_criteria(int value) const {
        return value >= threshold;
    }

    int operator()(int a, int b) const {
        return meets_criteria(b) ? a + b : a;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    //sum [5...10] = 45
    int sum;

    sum = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, my_conditional_binary_op);
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    //Use a function object to maintain states and additional parameters like 'threshold'
    sum = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, my_function_object(5));
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 30):

**Must** you really use an algorithm?
Something as simple as below won't do?

```
for (const auto& v: V)  if(pred(v)) sum+=v;
```

Sam's idea is also good.  But I would do it with lambda:

```
 sum = accumulate(
     V.begin(), V.end(), 0, 
     [](int a, int b){return pred(b)? a+b: a;}
 );
```

Comment: This is much preferred to the accepted 50 lines of code answer

Comment: I don't speak for OP, but - why do we even need `std::accumulate` at all for what is essentially just a loop? Why do we need `count_if` when we can adapt the iterator? etc.

Comment: Using std functions in general makes code more reliable.  E.g. notice that sum is not initialised to zero in the first example here.

Answer (score 8):

No, but you can write it [yourself](http://www.richelbilderbeek.nl/CppAccumulate_if.htm):

```
template
  <
  typename InputIterator,
  typename AccumulateType,
  typename BinaryOperation,
  typename Predicate
  >
const AccumulateType accumulate_if(
  InputIterator first,
  const InputIterator last,
  AccumulateType init,
  BinaryOperation&& binary_op,
  Predicate&& predicate)
{
  for (; first != last; ++first)
    if (predicate(*first)) init = binary_op(init, *first);
  return init;
}
```

Usage:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::cout << accumulate_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, std::plus<int>(), [] (int n) { return n > 3; });
    return 0;
} // outputs 9
```

Comment: I like the "write it yourself" style. Yeah the standard library is not omnipotent.

Comment: I'd take the function arguments by value (`BinaryOperation` and `Predicate`), to stay consistent with the Standard Library.

Comment: I like this answer. It is general enough to be reusable, and expresses intent so you don't have to read the operator or loop to figure out what is going on.