# QMetaObject finding class name in list of pointers

Tags: c++, qt

I have a RegistrationList class that has a function which is supposed to itterate over a list of Registration pointers and then return the total fees of a specific registration type passed to the function as a QString.  When I call this function from my gui implimentation class it always returns 0 even though I can see that there are registration pointers in the Registration list class.  Any idea what i'm doing wrong?  i'm guessing it has something to do with my use of QMetaObject but not sure.  The first function below is the RegistrationList function and the second is the slot in my gui class.

my Code:

```
double RegistrationList::totalFees(QString t) {
    double total = 0.00;
        for (int i = 0; i < attendeeList.size(); ++i) {
        if (attendeeList.at(i)->metaObject()->className() == t)
            total += attendeeList.at(i)->calculateFee();
    }


void MainWindow::totalFees_clicked() {
  if (ui->rdbGuest->isChecked()) {
      double total = m_rList.totalFees("GuestRegistration");
      QMessageBox::information(this, "Total guest registration fees", QString("Total guest registration fees: R    %1").arg(total), QMessageBox::Ok);
  }
  else if(ui->rdbStandard->isChecked()) {
      double total = m_rList.totalFees("StandardRegistration");
      QMessageBox::information(this, "Total standard registration fees", QString("Total standard registration     fees: R%1").arg(total), QMessageBox::Ok);
  }
  else if (ui->rdbStudent->isChecked()) {
      double total = m_rList.totalFees("StudentRegistration");
      QMessageBox::information(this, "Total student registration fees", QString("Total student registration     fees: R%1").arg(total), QMessageBox::Ok);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `DEFINES += QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII QT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII` to your project file, recompile your code, and fix all the bugs.

Hint: your `className` comparison with `t` doesn't do what you think it does. You're comparing pointers, where you should be comparing strings. Rewrite the test as one of the following:

1. `QString::fromLatin1(attendeeList.at(i)->metaObject()->className()) == t`, or
2. `!strcmp(attendeeList.at(i)->metaObject()->className(), t.toLatin1())`.

This operation should really be a member of the `Registration` class (if `attendeeList` contains values of type `Registration*`):

```
class Registration : public QObject {
   ...
public:
   bool is(const QString & className) const {
     return QString::fromLatin1(metaObject()->className()) == t;
   }
   ...
};
```

Your `totalFees` should be a `const` method, and then you don't need all the `at()` verbosity: the `operator[]` will do what you wish, then. You should also pass strings you don't need copies of by reference, not value. The use of iterators lets you get rid of the explicit indexing altogether:

```
double RegistrationList::totalFees(const QString & t) const {
  double total = 0.0;
  for (auto it = attendeeList.begin(); it != attendeeList.end(); ++it)
    if ((*it)->is(t)) total += (*it)->calculateFee();
  return total;
}
```

If your compiler supports range-for, you should use that instead. It's not the '00s anymore.

```
double RegistrationList::totalFees(const QString & t) const {
  double total = 0.00;
  for (auto attendee : attendeeList)
    if (attendee->is(t)) total += attendee->calculateFee();
  return total;
}
```

If you wish, you could also use `std::accumulate` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20028981/1329652)):

```
double RegistrationList::totalFees(const QString & t) const {
  return std::accumulate(attendeeList.begin(), attendeeList.end(), 0.0,
    [t](Registration* attendee) -> double {
      return attendee->is(t) ? attendee->calculateFee() : 0.0;
    });
}
```

Finally, you should never use floating point types to deal with money. Use a proper class to wrap an integer type to represent the lowest monetary unit you wish to deal with.

Comment: Thanks for that very detailed answer @Kuba Ober.  It works now.  So what was I comparing the strings to before?  I thought the pointer types held by the list of pointers also should have the same name as the classes they point to?

Comment: @user2094257 You were comparing pointer *values*, not the *pointed-to* values. You were getting the answer to the question "are these two homes at the same address", whereas you wanted the answer to "are these two homes the same". The former implies the latter, but not the other way round: the two tests aren't equivalent.