# Detecting and omitting na values from a std vector in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a std::vector; whose elements need to be summed up after checking if there is any Na values (and obviously removing the Na values if it has any) in it. I have to do it in Rcpp. Now, for a numeric vector in Rcpp (NumericVector); it is very easy as the code says below:

```
    cppFunction("
       double res ( NumericVector x){
         NumericVector v = x[! is_na(x)];
         return sum(v);
        }
        ")
```

. So for a vector "x", it easily gives the sum as follows:

```
       x<- c(NaN,1,2)
       res(x)
       [1] 3
```

Now for a std::vector   x; how can I do the same?

Comment: It is easy, but not efficient as you are allocating some intermediate vectors. Would be better to use a loop and it would work for std::vector as well.

Comment: Some alternative ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20028936/6103040

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use [RcppHoney](https://github.com/dcdillon/RcppHoney) (also on [CRAN here](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppHoney)) which brings the vectorised idioms of Rcpp Sugar (which has vectorised NA tests just like R has) to any iterable container -- hence also STL ones.

See eg the [into vignette](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppHoney/vignettes/introduction.html) for this example of combining different vector types and classes into a single scalar exppression:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector example_manually_hooked() {

    // We manually hooked std::list in to RcppHoney so we'll create one
    std::list< int > l;
    l.push_back(1); l.push_back(2); l.push_back(3); l.push_back(4); l.push_back(5);

    // std::vector is already hooked in to RcppHoney in default_hooks.hpp so
    // we'll create one of those too
    std::vector< int > v(l.begin(), l.end());

    // And for good measure, let's create an Rcpp::NumericVector which is
    // also hooked by default
    Rcpp::NumericVector v2(v.begin(), v.end());

    // Now do some weird operations incorporating std::vector, std::list,
    // Rcpp::NumericVector and some RcppHoney functions and return it.  The
    // return value will be equal to the following R snippet:
    //     v <- 1:5
    //     result <- 42 + v + v + log(v) - v - v + sqrt(v) + -v + 42

    // We can store our result in any of RcppHoney::LogicalVector,
    // RcppHoney::IntegerVector, or RcppHoney::NumericVector and simply return
    // it to R.  These classes inherit from their Rcpp counterparts and add a
    // new constructor.  The only copy of the data, in this case, is when we
    // assign our expression to retval.  Since it is then a "native" R type,
    // returning it is a shallow copy.  Alternatively we could write this as:
    //     return Rcpp::wrap(1 + v + RcppHoney::log(v) - v - 1
    //         + RcppHoney::sqrt(v) + -v2);

    RcppHoney::NumericVector retval
        =  42 + l + v + RcppHoney::log(v) - v - l + RcppHoney::sqrt(v) + -v2
            + 42;
    return retval;
}
```